# How can i check if someuser typed CTRL+S (control+s) in input textbox using php?

Tags: php, javascript, html, keyboard-events

How can I check if someuser types CTRL+S (control+s) in input textbox using php?

Checking that keyboard event, will it display the local characters or unicode characters like mathematical symbols?

How can I do it? Do I have to do it using javascript/jquery?

Suppose I have the mapping for unicode characters with some keyboad mapping, During submitting the data to server do I have to check the mapping of that typed character using PHP?

Think about commenting of a post in a blog.

Comment: You mean detecting Ctrl+S on a web page right? PHP only serves the page

Comment: Based on your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/13300793), I think you are thoroughly confused. What is it you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Is it the part of javascript/jquery only? Suppose i have the mapping for unicode characters with some keyboad mapping, During submitting the data to server do i have to check the mapping of that typed character using php?

Comment: Keyboard events and **characters** are two different things. You don't need to check keyboard events if you're interested in the **character** being entered.

Comment: I read the previous question, read the comments and facepalmed. Then i came back and facepalmed here as well.

Comment: Think about commenting of a post in a blog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using JQuery (as pointed out above PHP is just for serving)

```
$(document).keypress("s",function(e) {
  if(e.ctrlKey)
    alert("do something");
});
```

Comment: This alerts when I press Ctrl-Y too ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with PHP. This is a solution in jQuery (a JavaScript library)

```
$(window).keypress(function(event) {
if (!(event.which == 115 && event.ctrlKey) && !(event.which == 19)) return true;
alert("Ctrl-S pressed");
event.preventDefault();
return false;
});
```